# Programmatically creating a new QTextEdit inside a new tab

Tags: c++, qt

I have a tabwidget with QTextEdit having object name as "text_field" (Set through Qt Designer). It is inside one tab. Like for example, in a text editor, files are opened up in multiple tabs. I want to replicate this. So whenever I press "New File" button, it should programmatically create another tab with a new QTextEdit field. 
Also all the functions I have written so far are using the above mentioned object name, like

```
void MainWindow::some_function() {
    ...
    ui->text_field->textCursor();
    ...
}
```

As you can see, I have approached this in a wrong way. The problem is that how am I going to set the same object name for newly created QTextEdit when I press the "New File" button?

I tried something like this.

```
void MainWindow::on_actionNew_triggered()
{
    QTextEdit *text_field = new QTextEdit();
    ui->tabWidget->addTab(text_field,"Untitled.txt");
    ui->tabWidget->setCurrentWidget(text_field);
}
```

Result is that it is creating new tab, also adding a QTextEdit widget but the functions are only working for the originally created QTextEdit and not the one that is programmatically created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your textEdits stored in tabWidget, so you can easily access this widgets everywhere, just pass index of needed widget and you will be able do all what you need.

Example how to use.

```
for(int i = 0; i< ui->tabWidget->count(); i++ )
{
    qDebug() << ui->tabWidget->widget(i);
    QTextEdit* edit = qobject_cast<QTextEdit*>(ui->tabWidget->widget(i));
    if(edit)
        edit->setText("new");
}
```

In your example:

```
void MainWindow::some_function() {
    ...
    ui->text_field->textCursor();
    ...
}
```

you work with only widget which was created in Qt Designer, with my example using only index or just `currentIndex()` or `currentWidhet()` methods you can work with these. textEdits.

The main idea is that user can add many widgets and you can't predict how many user wants, but tabWidget store all widgets, so use it!

Comment: So I have to add `QTextEdit *te = qobject_cast<QTextEdit*>(ui->tabWidget->currentWidget());` to every function? Is there a way to get this done globally?

Comment: @Bhavyanshu currentWidget returns QWidget so you can't use this widget as textEdit without casting and checking is casting was succesful. If you want use it, you should cast, you can provide function to do this by one call of this function( but why? ). You can't do this more globallybecause you always should get actual widget, not a one widget which you set in your question.

Comment: Ok thank you for explaining. Also I have completely got rid of that first QTextEdit which wad added through Qt Designer. Now I am creating new tab and QTextEdit straight through `void MainWindow::on_actionNew_triggered()` function. I think this is still a better functionality. Thanks a lot for help!